# How to do animations in a Drawer navigation

Tags: react-native, animation, react-navigation

I've been searching for this all over the internet and it's driving me crazy.

I want to apply animations for when closing a screen on my app, but I want to use a Drawer navigator. All I've found is either for other navigators (stack, modal) or for handling the drawer itself.

Can anyone help me with this? I'm losing my mind over it

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?